# How do i convert an int retrieved from a database to string

Tags: c#, sql

I have a login form that I wanna select the `userID` (which is in the form of an `int`) from the database, and store it as a `string`.

```
string insertQuery = 
  "SELECT UserID FROM Customers WHERE Email = @Email AND Password = @Password";

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", tbEmail.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", tbPassword.Text);

string result = (string)com.ExecuteScalar();
```

But after I login, I get **this error**:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: Like this: `string insertQuery = "SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),UserID) FROM Customers WHERE Email = @Email AND Password = @Password";`

Comment: Instead of `(string)` in front if it, add `.ToString()` behind it.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What's wrong with keeping it an int?

Comment: If the value is an integer then use an `int` to read it.  This seems like an X-Y Problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using like below

```
string result = Convert.ToString(com.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 7):

What if the record *doesn't exist* (i.e. the cursor is *empty*)? Let's read and check if we have at least one record:

```
// Keep Sql being readable
string insertQuery = 
  @"SELECT UserID 
      FROM Customers 
     WHERE Email = @Email 
       AND Password = @Password";

// Do not forget to dispose IDisposable
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn)) {
  com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", tbEmail.Text);
  com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", tbPassword.Text);

  using (var reader = com.ExecuteReader()) {
    string result = reader.Read()
      ? Convert.ToString(reader[0]) // record exists
      : null;                       // cursor is empty

    //TODO: put relevant code which works with result here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution would be (assuming query always return result):

```
string result = com.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

You can cast as nvarchar in your query also:

```
string insertQuery = "SELECT cast(UserID as nvarchar) FROM Customers WHERE Email = @Email AND Password = @Password";
```

Answer (score 1):

[ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns Object type and you can convert it into which ever type you like

```
public override object ExecuteScalar ();
```

You can call it's ToString() method and it returns string form of it's value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
string result = string.Empty;

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(..);
..
object executedResult = com.ExecuteScalar();

if(executedResult != null) {
   result = executedResult.ToString();
}
```

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

Below are my findings

```
    string userID;

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
            string insertQuery = "SELECT UserID FROM Customers WHERE Email = @Email AND 
            Password = @Password";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", tbEmail.Text.ToString().Trim());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", tbPassword.Text.ToString().Trim());
            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
              userID = reader["UserID"].ToString();
            }
}
```